# Trying to add the objects to my canvas but the function of mycanvas.children.add() doesnt work,any other way?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I tried it with `rectangles` and it worked but i need to work with the piece which is

important for my clasess because they inherits from him. how do i add the objects to my `canvas`

if they are not `rectangle`?

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<Piece> arr_Enemy = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Piece>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Player _player = new Player(50,80, 50, 50, new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Background.jpg")));
        MyCanvas.Background = new ImageBrush
        {
            ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Background.jpg"))
        };
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(_player);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_Enemy.Count; i++)
        {
            arr_Enemy[i] = new Piece(rnd.Next(250), rnd.Next(500), 150, 120, new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/enemy.GIF")));
            MyCanvas.ChildrenTransitions.Add(arr_Enemy[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the player object? And have you checked the **children** property of the `Canvas `to make sure the player object is added successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add `UIElements` to the `Children` collecton of a `Canvas` just like you can only add `strings` to a `List<string>` for example.

If you `Player` is some kind of control, it should inherit from `UIElement`.

If `Player` is some kind of model, you could use an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` panel to display the models in your view:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ic" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListOfPlayers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Bind local:Player}">
            <TextBlock Text="I'm a player..." />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You would then add the players to the `ListOfPlayers` source collection.